# how to make a chat between two people with android socketio module on nodejs server?

Tags: android, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I work to develop a chat app with android on node.js server.I made a simple chat app.But everyone gets involved in the same room.I want to make a chat between only two people.How can I do that? What information should I send to the server?such as sender_name,receiver_name,message as a json format.

> -How can I to do list online-users?
>
> -And How can I start a chat between only two people?

*What are the requirements for it?*

Comment: > What information should I send to the server? - How do you think?    > I want to make a chat between only two people - Then make it, the question is ambiguous. > -How can I to do list online-users?  -  you keep a list of online users on a server and pass it to the client when needed.

Comment: how to keep a list of online users?. now I can send data (sender,message) but talking to anyone who connects to the server on a single screen.but I dont want this.When this is not the only two people have talked

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65787883/3904109 : for full working solution

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

I'd recommend setting up namespaces for each room you have your chat in. I did something similar in my own code. Note: Rooms and namespaces are a little different from each other in socket.io itself (socket.io has both: http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/).

In the Server code:

I have a method under socket.on('connection') that is similar to

```
socket.on('groupConnect', function(group){
    var groupNsp = io.of('/' + group);
}
```

This essentially makes sure that a namespace is exists under the name of the desired one. It doesn't mess it up or reset the namespace when it is called again.

Then for receiving the messages:

```
socket.on('message', function(data){
    var msg = data.msg;
    var nsp = data.nsp;
    io.of(nsp).emit('message', msg);
}
```

You could also add the nsp to the data you have already and then just send the data again to the clients.

Then, in the client code:

```
var socketOut = io.connect('http://yourdomain:1337/');
var someGroupOrMethodToGetGroup;
socketOut.emit('groupConnect', someGroupOrMethodToGetGroup);
var nsp;
setTimeout(function(){
    socket = io.connect('http://yourdomain:1377/' + someGroupOrMethodToGetGroup);
    socket.on('message', function(msg){
        displayMessage(msg);
    }
    nsp = '/' + someGroupOrMethodToGetGroup;
}, 1500);
```

Then in my displayMessage code I have:

```
socketOut.emit('message', { msg: desiredMessage, nsp: nsp });
```

From another answer of mine (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24805494/3842050).

Comment: You could set up namespaces for each pair of users who wish to chat, which is what you seem to want in the OP.

Comment: @OP Does this work? I haven't seen a response in nearly a month.