# socket.io namespaces or rooms or both

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am developing an App

1) There will be list of Emitters like "Emitter A", "Emitter B" (Web Browser/Mobile Device)

2) There will be a global Listener who listens to all Emitters Like "Global A" (Web Browser) Admin User

3) There will be specific Listener who will listen to only particular Emitter,  Listener A should only listen to Emitter A,  (listeners will be web browsers, mobile)

I hope i am able to explain you my problem,

Which will be the best way to achieve this with socket io

Comment: @Blubberguy22  i have found your answer quite useful on other socket question, can you help me with this one

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but if you still need help: what do you mean by the admin listener and the web browser listeners?

Comment: They will be the global listeners for all the emitters within their organization,
I have solved it by creating diff rooms for every emitter and Global will join all the rooms available under his organization, and (*3 Users) will join only to particular rooms.

Comment: @Blubberguy22 Now i have some doubt regarding how efficient or how costly it is to have idle socket connections. I mean will tons of idle socket connection will slow my server, or shall i connect and disconnect from socket soon after i finish my work, i mean after emitting events